# how to change image size in jssor slider?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the image size of a jssor slider. I changed the width of slider to 1920px but it does not affect the size of images. How I can change the size of images in Jssor Slider. I am using slider name Different Size Photo Slider which is available on jssor website. Please check the below codes and help me in this matter.

```
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif,arial,helvetica,verdana">

<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
<script src="js/jssor.slider-23.1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1200,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:-1,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5},$Brother:{$Duration:1200,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5},$Shift:90}},
          {$Duration:1400,x:0.25,$Zoom:1.5,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InWave,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InSine},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Brother:{$Duration:1400,x:-0.25,$Zoom:1.5,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InWave,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InSine},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10}},
          {$Duration:1200,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$Easing:{$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:1},$ZIndex:-10,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:-1,$Easing:{$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:1},$ZIndex:-10,$Shift:600}},
          {$Duration:1500,x:0.5,$Cols:2,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutCubic},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1500,$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1500,x:-0.3,y:0.5,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:0.1,$During:{$Left:[0.6,0.4],$Top:[0.6,0.4],$Rotate:[0.6,0.4],$Zoom:[0.6,0.4]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Top:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1000,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:-0.5,$Easing:{$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Shift:200}},
          {$Duration:1500,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:0.5,$During:{$Left:[0.4,0.6],$Top:[0.4,0.6],$Rotate:[0.4,0.6],$Zoom:[0.4,0.6]},$Easing:{$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1000,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:-0.5,$Easing:{$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Shift:200}},
          {$Duration:1500,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.6,0.4]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Outside:true,$Brother:{$Duration:1000,x:-0.3,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.25,y:0.5,$Rotate:-0.1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Top:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,x:-0.1,y:-0.7,$Rotate:0.1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Top:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1600,x:1,$Rows:2,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1600,x:-1,$Rows:2,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1600,x:1,$Rows:2,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1600,x:-1,$Rows:2,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1600,y:-1,$Cols:2,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1600,y:1,$Cols:2,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1200,y:1,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,y:-1,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,x:-1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-1,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,y:-1,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Shift:-100}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:1,$Delay:40,$Cols:6,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,x:1,$Delay:40,$Cols:6,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Shift:-100}},
          {$Duration:1500,x:-0.1,y:-0.7,$Rotate:0.1,$During:{$Left:[0.6,0.4],$Top:[0.6,0.4],$Rotate:[0.6,0.4]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Top:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1000,x:0.2,y:0.5,$Rotate:-0.1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Top:$Jease$.$InQuad,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InQuad},$Opacity:2}},
          {$Duration:1600,x:-0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$During:{$Left:[0.4,0.6]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$InOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Top:0.5},$Brother:{$Duration:1000,x:0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:1028,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$InOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Top:0.5}}}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $FillMode: 5,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*responsive code begin*/
        /*remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodywidth = jssor_1_slider.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodywidth)
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));

            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();
            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*responsive code end*/
    };
</script>
<style>
    /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 13 css */
    /*
    .jssorb13 div           (normal)
    .jssorb13 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
    .jssorb13 .av           (active)
    .jssorb13 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
    .jssorb13 .dn           (mousedown)
    */
    .jssorb13 {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .jssorb13 div, .jssorb13 div:hover, .jssorb13 .av {
        position: absolute;
        /* size of bullet elment */
        width: 21px;
        height: 21px;
        background: url('img/b13.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .jssorb13 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
    .jssorb13 div:hover, .jssorb13 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
    .jssorb13 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
    .jssorb13 .dn, .jssorb13 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }
</style>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1345px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);"></div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1345px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/03.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/04.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/05.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/06.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/07.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/08.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/09.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/10.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/11.jpg" />
        </div>
        <a data-u="any" href="https://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">slider bootstrap</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
    <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb13" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;" data-autocenter="1">
        <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
        <div data-u="prototype" style="width:21px;height:21px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">jssor_1_slider_init();</script>
<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
```

Comment: Provide codes you have been using

Comment: please check the post again

Comment: I am working on this slider https://www.jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.slider plz visit the link

Comment: I guess you have configure it from their site and get the code.... because i couldn't find any documentation to edit the code directly

Comment: you should download (Export) slider form this link https://www.jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.slider , you will get whole document and images by which you will easyly understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to change `$FillMode: 5` to `$FillMode: 0`. This will stretch images to fill full area of slide. Also divs with width:1345px, should be 1920. You can find more here https://www.jssor.com/help/layout.html, under “Fill Mode (Slide)”. I hope this will help.

Comment: Great! Happy to help!